# Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR HubCallerContext Context returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

I've got an app on ASP.NET Core where I'm trying to implement SignalR communications between server side and client side code. In a class that implements Hub abstract class I've got a method where I'm trying to add a new connected user. But the inherited property - `public HubCallerContext Context { get; set; }` from Hub class that is supposed to get the connectionId is null. The above looks like this:

```
public class TestHub : Hub, ITestHub
{
    private IHubContext<TestHub> _hubContext;

    public ChatHub(IHubContext<TestHub> context)
    {
        _hubContext = context;
    }

    public void Connect(string userName)
    {
        var id = Context.ConnectionId;//The property in null

        if (!Users.Any(x => x.ConnectionId == id))
        {
            Users.Add(new User { ConnectionId = id, Name = userName });
            Clients.Caller.onConnected(id, userName, Users);
            Clients.AllExcept(id).onNewUserConnected(id, userName);
        }
    }
}
```

I have configurations in startup class such as:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddSignalR();//registering SignalR
    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie();
    services.RegisterServices();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    //some code
    app.UseSignalR(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub");
    });
    //some code
}
```

I get my IHubContext _context when call (ServiceProvider)provider.GetService() by dependecy injection, but any properties of the inhertied Hub class are null. How would I get to use them? Am I missing something?

Comment: Tested you code. The ConnectionId is not null. Just back to the basic code by commenting all code and not deriveing and not using DI and check step by step what is wrong.